# what is lookup used for in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to understand what exactly the function "lookup" does in terraform code? does it find maps or lists? just confused how to use this lookup correctly.

Comment: Have you referred this => https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/lookup.html ??

Answer (score 3):

[The `lookup` documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/lookup.html) has the following to say about it:

> `lookup` retrieves the value of a single element from a map, given its key. If the given key does not exist, the given default value is returned instead.

The normal way to look up a value from a map by key is to use [the index syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#indices-and-attributes), like `example["foo"]`, but that operation will return an error if there is no element with the key `foo` in the map `example`.

`lookup` is therefore similar to the index syntax except for the additional behavior of choosing a fallback value to use instead of an error if the key doesn't exist. `lookup(example, "foo", "default")` is the same as `example["foo"]` except that it will produce `"default"` rather than an error if there is no element with the key `"foo"`.

More recent Terraform versions also have [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html) which can serve as a perhaps easier to understand alternative to `lookup`, because it still uses the normal index syntax as part of the expression: `try(example["foo"], "default")` is similar to `lookup(example, "foo", "default")`, and will produce the same result as long as `example` is a map of strings.